# Laravel ignore duplicate query request

Tags: php, sql, laravel

So in my laravel application i made a filter for the 'file' field.

i made this filter for different roles (admin, partner)
First i made it working on the partner side (this shows all the file's accesable for that role (not all the files) and this works 100%.
but now i want to make it working for the admin, (acces to all the file's)
but this just does not work because it always returns this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
SQL:
select * from `file` where `id` in (9, 11, 9, 11, 9, 11, 9, 11, 9, 11)
```

As you can see there are duplicate entry's . is there a way to ignore this error and just load in the file's. if i copy paste the query in SQL itself, it just works.

code for the admin filters:

```
    if ($tag_id != 0 && $langs != 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                $fileCount = File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->pluck('file_id')->count();
                $file[] = $fileCount > 0 ? File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->pluck('file_id') : null;
            }
            $this->AdminFiles = File::whereIn('id', $file)->where('language_id', $langs)->get();
        } else if ($tag_id != 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                $fileCount = File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->pluck('file_id')->count();
                $file[] = $fileCount > 0 ? File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->pluck('file_id') : null;
            }
            $this->AdminFiles = File::whereIn('id', $file)->get();
        } else if ($langs != 0) {
            $this->files = File::where('language_id', $langs)->get();
        } else {
            $this->AdminFiles = File::all();
        }
```

code for the partner filter (working)

```
if($tag_id != 0 && $langs != 0)
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_role); $i++) {
                $fileCount = File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id')->count();
                $file[] = $fileCount > 0 ? File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id') : null;
                }
                $this->files = File::whereIn('id', $file)->where('language_id', $langs)->get(); 
        }
        
       else if ($tag_id != 0) {                
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_role); $i++) {
                    $fileCount = File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id')->count();
                    $file[] = $fileCount > 0 ? File_Tag::where('tag_id', $tag_id)->where('file_id', '=', $file_role[$i])->pluck('file_id') : null;
                    }
                    $this->files = File::whereIn('id', $file)->get();        
            
        }
       else if($langs != 0) {
            $this->files = File::whereIn('id', $file_role)->where('language_id', $langs)->get();

    }
        else {
            $this->files = File::whereIn('id',$file_role)->get();
        }
```

Comment: @KennyHorna I'm just trying to understand the purpose to Lavarel.  I  do not understand why someone would add such complication to a simple query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you want to filter files based on (1) a given file tag (if present) and also filter them based on (2) a given set of languages (if present). The (3) role part is not that clear for me but I think you can adjust the following code to include that constraint too.

Whenever you want to apply constraints in your query base on conditions, you can make use of [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#conditional-clauses).

This just apply the constraint to the query when a condition is met.

(1) Filter based on the role tag. You can create the relationship between File and FileTag to then use the relationship to filter values between the tables:

```php
$files = File::query()
    // This tells Laravel than whenever $tag_id != 0, will apply the filter
    ->when($tag_id != 0, function ($query) use ($tag_id) {
        $query->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tag_id) {
            $query->where('id', $tag_id);
        }
    })
    ->get();
```

(2) Then, you want to also apply a filter if a language is provided:

```php
$files = File::query()
    ->when($langs, function ($query) use ($langs) {
        $query->where('language_id', $langs);
    })
    ->get();
```

The cool part is that you can chain them. So at the end you can do:

```php
$files = File::query()
    ->when($tag_id != 0, function ($query) use ($tag_id) {
        $query->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tag_id) {
            $query->where('id', $tag_id);
        }
    })
    ->when($langs, function ($query) use ($langs) {
        $query->where('language_id', $langs);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: very usefull!, this is something i can use in the future aswell!